# How to Auto-Resize a JTextpane

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, jtextpane

I want to make a jtextpane auto resized

It means when I enter text the width of textpane should increase based on text

when I press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key from keyboard the height of textpane should increase based on the ENTER key

How is it possible

Thanks in advance

Comment: I want to make a jtextpane auto resized - please which of possible directions

Comment: Add it to panel with a GridBagLayout and see what happens

Comment: Or user something like this http://java-sl.com/tip_text_height_measuring.html to measure your content's width

Comment: Use a documentlistener that resizes the textpane based on the size calculated by StanislavL's answer